# Was it wise for Ned Stark to promise Jon they would talk about his mother?

Tags: game-of-thrones

## Context

- I'm basing this question on the TV show only, up to the end of Season 6 [so, minor spoiler ahead].
- I'm not using the R+L=J theory, because it's still a theory and not necessary here.
- I didn't read the books, but any information from them that doesn't diverge from the show is welcome !

### Facts leading to this question

- Ned said to Jon : "**the next time we see each other, we'll talk about your mother**" (Season 1 Ep 2)
- As he's described, Ned doesn't take engagements lightly.
- Given the very obvious visual hint (eyes close-up transition), Jon is considered as Lyanna's son (Season 6 Ep 10)
- Lyanna was afraid Robert would kill the baby if he knew (same episode)

## Question

> Given the possible consequences of revealing who is Jon's mother, probably also his father and the context of his birth, **was it wise, honorable, moral** from Ned to promise to tell Jon ?

### Different approaches that may help address the question

- **Honor angle** : First, it was very likely Ned and Jon would never see each other again. Ned did intend to tell Jon if they both survived long enough, but that could be after a very long time.
- **Moral angle** : Ned was probably waiting for Jon to be a "brother of the night's watch" so that the truth would change nothing for Jon's future : you can't leave the night's watch, *unless you die first*. But isn't that unfair ? Jon might have refused joining the night's watch if he had known, so Ned is depriving Jon from his free will, in a way.
- **Wisdom angle** : Would Ned have revealed the truth to Jon *only* ? In fact, even if he tell *only* to Jon, nothing guaranties that Jon wouldn't tell other people, or that spies would hear and everything would be known. So he must have considered the risk of everybody knowing. Then, how would Robert have reacted ? He couldn't guess Robert would be dead, so it *could* have been lethal even after all those years, even if Jon "took the black". Similarly, how would Catelyn react ? He didn't trust her for two decades, after all.

As you see, I'm tempted to answer "no it wasn't wise, honorable and moral". Maybe it was just *nice*, *sensible*. But I would be interested to read your thoughts about it, in case I missed something or if the books offer different views. Thanks !

---

### EDIT :

As was well explained in the comments, we don't know enough to conclude anything. I can't really change the question to make it answerable.

However, one important thing I overlooked is that **Ned *had to* tell Jon** from another moral perspective : not intending to tell would have been worse than just ignoring **Jon's hope to know**.
This morality aspect is probably what motivated Ned's decision as Mooz proposed in the comments. Even if it was risky and a bit dishonest, Jon deserved to hope he would know.

Also, from a psychological point of view, promises like that tend to create a link between characters, and could make them a bit stronger in life. Like if it were a self-realizing prophecy.

However, from a point of view outside of the story evoked by Ber in comments, these kind of promises are set up by the author so that readers/viewers would be even more chocked in the case one of the characters dies. One could say ironically "*No, Ned wasn't wise because making such a promise had him killed by the author*". But I'm relieved to notice that there are cases where it doesn't happen. (example of Sansa saying to LittleFinger "I expect I'll be a married woman by the time you return")

Comment: From the "Honor Angle", Ned probably did not expect to see Jon for a long time. Ned would be in Kings Landing while Jon was on the Wall. Robert hadn't been to Winterfell in ages (IIRC 8-10 years), and I doubt Robert would want Ned gone for months just to visit his bastard. Your "Moral angle" I agree with once Jon is part of the NW he effectively untouchable. If Robert knew about Aemon surely he would have had him killed. Wisdom angle, once Jon is on the wall the only people he can tell are the brothers.

Comment: If you're basing your question on the show, then how is R+L=J still a theory?

Comment: Oh, also... Welcome to SFF.SE!!

Comment: Also, also, this might be opinion based... "talk about your mother" doesn't necessarily translate into "I will tell you the identity of her"

Comment: @Skooba I agree with your comments, but (1)Ned and Jon could see each other anyway even after long (2)Did Robert know about Aemon in the NW ? I assumed nobody knew. (3)I also assumed there could be some kind of spies in the NW too. About "talk about your mother", I thought it was too much "hype" for not revealing at least her identity.

Comment: @Mooz Thanks ! AFAIK nothing is absolutely clear about Jon's father in Season06. I even first believed it was Ned. ;)

Comment: @GhislainBugnicourt I think that's the point. I'll do this thing in the future is foreshadowing that the event will likely never happen. It's designed to crush ours as well as Jon's dreams. The same as when Robb told Jon `"the next time I see you, you'll be all in black"`... Then they proceeed to never see each other again.

Comment: As far as the actual question goes, **I believe Ned felt that he owed it to Jon**. Jon has lived his entire life not knowing (or having the courage to ask) anything about his mother. He finally is old enough and asks, so Ned promises to tell him. He happens to keep his honour by being beheaded first though.

Comment: This is difficult to answer, because we know Ned promised Lyanna something, but not exactly what that was. That adds dimensions to the moral and honor angle.

Comment: My not-so-flippant, out-of-universe answer: Because according to the Fatal Family Photo rule, it tells us they will never see each other again. (I called it when I saw it, and I hadn't read that far into the book.) Whenever you see anyone, in any media, say "next time we meet, I'll tell you about my father" that person will die. If the character's mentor pulls them aside to actually tell them about their parents, that person is dead in the next reel. Screenwriters can't help but honor tradition...

Comment: Three things you should never do if you want to survive, even on HBO: 1) promise to tell the protagonist some vital bit of info next time you see them. 2) discover the details of the evil plot, and tell the protagonist that the next time you meet they'll have all the info needed to wrap up the plot neatly. (if you try and actually tell them, you'll die mid-sentence). 3) reveal that you are pining for a specific family member back home.

Comment: Thks for your comments guys. I'll edit the OP to make it clear : there's too much we don't know to really answer this question (yet?). At least I have the most valuable information to me : I didn't miss anything important that would change the entire reflexion. :) @Ber I was angry at you for showing me a pattern that reveals when bad things would happen, but then I realized we have at least one counter-example : Sansa said to LittleFinger "I expect I'll be a married woman by the time you return". They did see each other again.

Comment: It may not be that complicated. He could have been just explicitly waiting for him to take the black to tell him, once he does that, past crimes and presumably past grudges against him due to his family are forgiven. So Ned could safely reveal his parentage to him. There is, after all, another safely staying at castle black that Ned likely knew about.